# Jquery off not removing event handler in Ember application

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js

I am not able to remove a event handler from the ember application by using off.

my handler function is

```
setClickEvent: function(){
  var panel = this.$();
  if(panel && panel.find(event.target).length === 0 && this.get('isOpen')){
    this.send('cancel');
  }
}
```

and I am calling this function in `didInsertElement` function using the below code

```
didInsertElement: function(){
  Ember.$('body').on('click', Ember.run.bind(this, this.setClickEvent));
}
```

and calling the `off` in `willDestroyElement` function as below

```
willDestroyElement: function(){
  Ember.$('body').off('click', this.setClickEvent);
  this._super();
}
```

I tried to go through many stackoverflow questions related to it. Which suggested to place an empty `on` after the `off`, I tried it but it didn't work.

The problem is that whenever I am moving away from the page and coming back I am finding two handlers handling the same event, because the previous event handler has not got removed and the event handlers are getting stacked up.

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle showing the issue ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's unrelated to ember actually. The issue is this part:

```
Ember.run.bind(this, this.setClickEvent)
```

What it does is `bind` creates a **new function** bound to `this`. Then that new function is attached as a handler. However, you try to `off()` the original `setClickEvent` instead of the new function.

Try to bind the function when the object is created and store it for later use:

```
init: function () {
  this._super();
  this._setClickEvent = Ember.run.bind(this, this.setClickEvent);
}
```

Then in your `didInsertElement` and `willDestroyElement`, use the bound function directly, `this._setClickEvent`.

The point being `off` must be given the exact function that was given to `on`, otherwise it will not find it in its watcher list and will not remove it.

Comment: this fixed the code and thanks for the explanation too.